# Angular tsconfig.ts paths absolute imports doesn't resolve modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having an issue when absolute imports in Angular doesn't work as expected. With the following settings

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        ...
        "paths": {
            "@models/*": [
                "src/app/models/*"
            ]
        }
    }
}

// tsconfig.app.json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.e2e.ts"
  ]
}
```

Directory structure is as follows:

```
/src/app/models
               /index.ts
               /my-model.ts
// index.ts
export * from './my-model';
```

The following imports **works** as expected

```
import { MyModel } from '../../models';
import { MyModel } from '@models/index';
```

but the following **doesn't work**, whereas it should

```
import { MyModel } from '@models';
```

**Update 1:** if I change path definition as follows:

```
"@models/*": [
    "src/app/models/*",
    "src/app/models/"
]
```

following import works as well

```
import { MyModel } from '@models/';
```

**Update 2:** just noticed that with following settings:

```
"@models/*": [
    "app/models/*"
]
```

following import **works only for angular cli**, even though vc code complains that the component can't be found

```
import { MyModel } from '@models/';
```

**Update 3:** interesting observation. Just looked at paths config for another project (generated by by cli) and paths defined as follows:

```
"paths": {
    "@models": [
        "src/app/models"
    ],
    "@models/*": [
        "src/app/models/*"
    ],
}
```

And with this setup import works as expected with:

```
import { MyModel } from '@models';
```

So now, the question is whether this is TS or Angular CLI?

Comment: Also add "@models": [
                "src/app/models"
            ] might help?

Comment: @MikeOne if add this config it changes something.. But not entirely - see an update. Looks like baseUrl issue.

Comment: Check. At least it seems to work now right? I might also do a —prod build to make sure your solution keeps working - just to be safe..

Comment: Its not a solution - its a workaround. I used absolute paths in 3 different projects without any problems. Something is causing this issue.

Comment: I also use them a lot - and also sometimes run into issues. My IDE also sometimes can’t resolve the import.. only after a few reboots it ‘suddenly’ sees it. Not sure why..

Comment: @MikeOne thank you. Misunderstand your first comment - you nailed it.. See an update.

Comment: Glad it worked.